# Multi GPU Compiz?

Tags: multi-monitor, gpu, compiz, xinerama

Is it possible to enable OpenGL compositing in multi GPU setup?

I have Quadro 4000 and GTX580. Atm I'm using xinerama and 4 X servers but it doesn't support Compiz. On the other hand I can't find a way to configure it with single X server.

If cards would be identical, connected via SLI would it be easier to achieve?